# c# Update object in List using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an viewmodel that has some relationships built.

```
public class object()
{
    public int Id  {get; set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
}

public class myViewModel()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<object> myObjects {get;set;}

}
```

What I would like to do is change the Amount for a specific myObject element given the object name.

```
var query = new myViewModel();
```

Assume that I have populated data into the myObjects List.

```
var record = query.myobjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "Test");
```

Pulls the correct element from this list, but how to update the vale within the list is what I am stuck on. I have tried:

```
query.myObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test").Amount = 99;
```

and

```
query.myObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test") == record;
```

neither works.

Comment: `public class object()` is not valid class declaration

Comment: Neither is `public class myViewModel()`...

Comment: What "doesn't work" with the first one? For the second one, why are you comparing `FirstOrDefault(...)` to `result`?

Comment: basically you create a method UpdateAmount and go stepwise, e.g.

Comment: Please show your actual code, as the posted one doesn´t compile at all and thus isn´t adequate to reproduce your issue.

Comment: notice in this line you need to use  == instad of = : `var record = query.myobjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "Test");` Like `var record = query.myobjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test");`

Comment: I can't post the answer I typed up as its been marked as duplicate but I did create a dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2focv8 Using code similar to what you said you tried first, I am successfully able to update the object's property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the complete code I ran in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var query = new myViewModel();
    query.myObjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Test").Amount = 99;  
    query.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class objectX
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class myViewModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<objectX> myObjects { get; set; }

    public myViewModel()
    {
        myObjects = new List<UserQuery.objectX>();
        myObjects.Add(new objectX { Amount = 100, Id = 1, Name = "ABC" });
        myObjects.Add(new objectX { Amount = 200, Id = 2, Name = "Test" });
        myObjects.Add(new objectX { Amount = 300, Id = 3, Name = "GHI" });
    }

}
```

output:

List (3 items)
Id | Name | Amount

1 | ABC | 100

2 | Test | 99

3 | GHI | 300

| | 499

Comment: James thanks, also mentions for MegaTron as this also fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

'You question shows you should go & read a good C# book...

basically you are confusing = and ==. What you could do is create a method and proceed step-wise, e.g.

```
public class myViewModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<object> myObjects {get;set;}

    public bool ChangeAmountByName(string name, decimal amount)
    {
        var match = this.myobjects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
        if (match == null) return false;

        match.Amount = amount;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is just one of several possible solutions. But it is always important to "divide and conquer", i.e. split your task into steps: Here it is: First get your matching record. Verify it is there; react somehow it is missing. Then do your value update!